# displaying arraylist of type bean using jstl in jsp

Tags: model-view-controller

I am new to JSTL. I need to get the content of database and display it in jsp. I am using mvc for this purpose. I have servlet which retrives data from table and stores it in arraylist of type bean class. I am forwarding the arraylist to jsp page where i am using forEach jstl to display arraylist. But i am getting error
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /Retrievedata.jsp at line 89

86:             
87:       
88:         
89:           
90:           
91:         
92:

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:510)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:401)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    stepack.ReqServlet.doPost(ReqServlet.java:60)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: An error occurred while evaluating custom action attribute "value" with value "${current.Title}": Unable to find a value for "Title" in object of class "stepack.Reqbean" using operator "." (null)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:862)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:791)
    org.apache.jsp.Retrievedata_jsp._jspService(Retrievedata_jsp.java:189)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    stepack.ReqServlet.doPost(ReqServlet.java:60)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

root cause

javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: An error occurred while evaluating custom action attribute "value" with value "${current.Title}": Unable to find a value for "Title" in object of class "stepack.Reqbean" using operator "." (null)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.lang.jstl.Evaluator.evaluate(Evaluator.java:131)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.lang.jstl.Evaluator.evaluate(Evaluator.java:151)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.lang.support.ExpressionEvaluatorManager.evaluate(ExpressionEvaluatorManager.java:97)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.ExpressionUtil.evalNotNull(ExpressionUtil.java:70)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.OutTag.evaluateExpressions(OutTag.java:121)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.OutTag.doStartTag(OutTag.java:79)
    org.apache.jsp.Retrievedata_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fout_005f0(Retrievedata_jsp.java:254)
    org.apache.jsp.Retrievedata_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(Retrievedata_jsp.java:216)
    org.apache.jsp.Retrievedata_jsp._jspService(Retrievedata_jsp.java:150)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    stepack.ReqServlet.doPost(ReqServlet.java:60)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.29 logs.

The code is as follows:
in jsp
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>

Servlet:

public class ReqServlet extends HttpServlet

{    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {

```
    try 
    {   

        ArrayList<Reqbean> row = new ArrayList<Reqbean>();      .........
    String q="SELECT "...........;
    Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery(q);
    boolean report=res.next();
    if(report)
    {
    do
    {
    Reqbean req=new Reqbean();
    // Selecting values from ResultSet and storing them in Reqbean class
    req.setId(res.getString(1));
    req.setTitle(res.getString(2));

    // adding Reqbean object to ArrayList
    row.add(req);
    System.out.println("adding");
    }while(res.next());
    }
    res.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();

        request.setAttribute("row", row);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        request.setAttribute("error", "Retrieving rows failed.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    request.getRequestDispatcher("Retrievedata.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{   

}
```

}

Reqbean class:
public class Reqbean{
    public String Id;
    public String Title;
    public void setId(String val)
    {
        this.Id=val;
    }
    public String getId()
    {
        return Id;
    }
    public void setTitle(String val)
    {
        this.Title=val;
    }
    public String getTitle()
    {
        return Title;
    }
}

I have placed jstl.jar and standard.jar in WEB-INF/lib folder 
Please help me.................

Answer (score 0):

`${current.Title}` (which I assume is in your jsp somewhere) should be `${current.title}`

And in your Reqbean: `public String title;`

Comment: Hi, to thank me, you can accept my answer by clicking the 'V' on the left of it. Welcome to stackoverflow :)